# Shouldn't TclInvalidateStringRep() reset length?

Tags: tcl

I have a doubt on the following code in TCL 8.6.8 source tclInt.h:

```
4277 #define TclInvalidateStringRep(objPtr) \
4278     if (objPtr->bytes != NULL) { \
4279         if (objPtr->bytes != tclEmptyStringRep) { \
4280             ckfree((char *) objPtr->bytes); \
4281         } \
4282         objPtr->bytes = NULL; \
4283     }
```

This macro is called by Tcl_InvalidateStringRep() in tclObj.c.

My doubt is, why doesn't tclObj's length get reset to zero?

Here is from definition of Tcl_Obj:

```
 808 typedef struct Tcl_Obj {
 809     int refCount;               /* When 0 the object will be freed. */
 810     char *bytes;                /* This points to the first byte of the
 811                                  * object's string representation. The array
 812                                  * must be followed by a null byte (i.e., at
 813                                  * offset length) but may also contain
 814                                  * embedded null characters. The array's
 815                                  * storage is allocated by ckalloc. NULL means
 816                                  * the string rep is invalid and must be
 817                                  * regenerated from the internal rep.  Clients
 818                                  * should use Tcl_GetStringFromObj or
 819                                  * Tcl_GetString to get a pointer to the byte
 820                                  * array as a readonly value. */
 821     int length;                 /* The number of bytes at *bytes, not
 822                                  * including the terminating null. */
```

So you can see length is tightly coupled with bytes, when bytes is cleared, shouldn't we reset length?

My doubt comes from the following code, TclCreateLiteral() in tclLiteral.c:

```
 200     for (globalPtr=globalTablePtr->buckets[globalHash] ; globalPtr!=NULL;
 201             globalPtr = globalPtr->nextPtr) {
 202         objPtr = globalPtr->objPtr;
 203         if ((globalPtr->nsPtr == nsPtr)
 204                 && (objPtr->length == length) && ((length == 0)
 205                 || ((objPtr->bytes[0] == bytes[0])
 206                 && (memcmp(objPtr->bytes, bytes, (unsigned) length) == 0)))) {
```

So at line 204, when length is not zero while bytes is NULL, the program crashes.

My product includes TCL source and I find the above problem when I trace a program crash. I put the workaround in our code, but like to confirm with the community if it indeed is a vulnerability.

Comment: That looks like a bug in `TclCreateLiteral` to me; it shouldn't touch the `length` field directly if the `bytes` field is NULL. Using the `TclGetStringFromObj` macro to extract those fields (instead of poking around directly inside the structure) ensures that the semantics is correct.

Comment: Also, how are you triggering this code path? If we're going to test for it (and we should!) then we need to reproduce it…

Answer (score 0):

I've had a think about this, and while I believe that the code that is purging the representation is wrong to do so (since the object should in principle be shared and so shouldn't be observed to change) I certainly think that it is extremely difficult to actually prove that that can't happen. For sure, `TclCreateLiteral` in `tclLiteral.c` shouldn't blow up if it happens!

[The fix](https://core.tcl.tk/tcl/info/da7b45afb48b3ecb) I'm using is to make `TclCreateLiteral` use `TclGetStringFromObj` (the Tcl-internal macro-ized version of `Tcl_GetStringFromObj`) to get the `bytes` and `length` fields instead of using them directly, so that the correct constraints are preserved. *This should make the string representation exist once more if it is removed.* If the code continues to crash, the problem is your code that is calling `TclInvalidateStringRep` on a literal (and setting a type that can't have a string generated for it; Tcl has some of those, but that's because it never purges the original string from them).

Remember, a `Tcl_Obj` should only have its string rep purged when it becomes *wrong,* not just when it gains a non-string representation. The fact a value has been interpreted as an integer doesn't mean that it shouldn't be interpretable as a list (quite the reverse!) and if the internal representation is never updated to a different value (in-place modifications should only ever happen to unshared objects) it should never need to lose that string representation at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your aproach seems to be wrong somewhere.

The call of `TclInvalidateStringRep` is basically allowed for objects with no references (`refCount == 0`) or with exactly one reference (so `refCount <= 1`) and then only if you are sure, that this 1 reference is your own reference only.

Tcl's **shared objects** could switch its internal representation, but the string representation remains immutable. Otherwise you will break the basic principles of Tcl (like EIAS, etc).

Simplest example that can explain this:

```
set k 0x7f
dict set d $k test
expr {$k};             # ==> 127 (obj is integer now, but...)
puts $k;               # ==> 0x7f (... still remains the string-representation)
puts [dict get $d $k]; # ==> test

# some code that fouls it up (despite of two references var `k` and key in dict `d`):
magic_happens_here $k; # string representation gets lost.

# and hereafter:
puts $k;               # ==> 127 (representation is now 127, so...)
puts [dict get $d $k]; # ==> ERROR: key "127" not known in dictionary
```

As you can see, **reset resp. altering of the string representation of shared object** is wrong by design.
Please avoid this in Tcl.